# Google cloud data flow INTERNAL: GOAWAY received

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We are using google cloud dataflow to create a cache of data to make our web requests fast. The dataset and how it gets grouped together is slightly out of our control, so we are doing some very unorthodox things. Anyway, we have been getting this error every once in a while, but the job will sometimes continue to run and succeed.
JobID:2017-12-19_22_30_10-4314752451342817881

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: unexpected
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:182)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:104)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.processElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.java:121)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.processElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.java:53)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:117)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:74)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:113)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:187)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:148)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:68)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:330)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:302)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:251)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:135)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:115)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:102)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: unexpected
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:36)
 at com.monsanto.product360.beam.dataflow.materialviews.groupers.CabnAuspGrouper$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:141)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:324)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:272)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:66)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:436)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:424)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.join.CoGroupByKey$ConstructCoGbkResultFn.processElement(CoGroupByKey.java:206)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.join.CoGroupByKey$ConstructCoGbkResultFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:141)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:324)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:180)
 ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: unexpected
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.CachingShuffleBatchReader.read(CachingShuffleBatchReader.java:79)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.BatchingShuffleEntryReader$ShuffleReadIterator.fillEntries(BatchingShuffleEntryReader.java:133)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.BatchingShuffleEntryReader$ShuffleReadIterator.fillEntriesIfNeeded(BatchingShuffleEntryReader.java:126)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.BatchingShuffleEntryReader$ShuffleReadIterator.hasNext(BatchingShuffleEntryReader.java:90)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.ForwardingReiterator.hasNext(ForwardingReiterator.java:62)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.GroupingShuffleEntryIterator$ValuesIterator.advance(GroupingShuffleEntryIterator.java:283)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.GroupingShuffleEntryIterator$ValuesIterator.hasNext(GroupingShuffleEntryIterator.java:278)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupingShuffleReader$GroupingShuffleReaderIterator$ValuesIterator.hasNext(GroupingShuffleReader.java:357)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.PeekingReiterator.computeNext(PeekingReiterator.java:94)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.PeekingReiterator.hasNext(PeekingReiterator.java:48)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn$WindowReiterator.skipToValidElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.java:226)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn$WindowReiterator.hasNext(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.java:202)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Iterators$PeekingImpl.hasNext(Iterators.java:1105)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.join.CoGbkResult$UnionValueIterator.advance(CoGbkResult.java:430)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.join.CoGbkResult$UnionValueIterator.hasNext(CoGbkResult.java:407)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.MultitransformedIterator.hasNext(MultitransformedIterator.java:47)
 at com.monsanto.product360.beam.dataflow.materialviews.groupers.CabnAuspGrouper.processElement(CabnAuspGrouper.java:35)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: INTERNAL: GOAWAY received
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:500)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:459)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:76)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:142)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2373)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2337)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2295)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2208)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4053)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4057)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4986)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.CachingShuffleBatchReader.read(CachingShuffleBatchReader.java:76)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.BatchingShuffleEntryReader$ShuffleReadIterator.fillEntries(BatchingShuffleEntryReader.java:133)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.BatchingShuffleEntryReader$ShuffleReadIterator.fillEntriesIfNeeded(BatchingShuffleEntryReader.java:126)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.BatchingShuffleEntryReader$ShuffleReadIterator.hasNext(BatchingShuffleEntryReader.java:90)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.ForwardingReiterator.hasNext(ForwardingReiterator.java:62)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.GroupingShuffleEntryIterator$ValuesIterator.advance(GroupingShuffleEntryIterator.java:283)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.GroupingShuffleEntryIterator$ValuesIterator.hasNext(GroupingShuffleEntryIterator.java:278)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupingShuffleReader$GroupingShuffleReaderIterator$ValuesIterator.hasNext(GroupingShuffleReader.java:357)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.PeekingReiterator.computeNext(PeekingReiterator.java:94)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.PeekingReiterator.hasNext(PeekingReiterator.java:48)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn$WindowReiterator.skipToValidElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.java:226)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn$WindowReiterator.hasNext(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.java:202)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Iterators$PeekingImpl.hasNext(Iterators.java:1105)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.join.CoGbkResult$UnionValueIterator.advance(CoGbkResult.java:430)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.join.CoGbkResult$UnionValueIterator.hasNext(CoGbkResult.java:407)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.MultitransformedIterator.hasNext(MultitransformedIterator.java:47)
 at com.monsanto.product360.beam.dataflow.materialviews.groupers.CabnAuspGrouper.processElement(CabnAuspGrouper.java:35)
 at com.monsanto.product360.beam.dataflow.materialviews.groupers.CabnAuspGrouper$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:141)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:324)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:272)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:66)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:436)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:424)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.join.CoGroupByKey$ConstructCoGbkResultFn.processElement(CoGroupByKey.java:206)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.join.CoGroupByKey$ConstructCoGbkResultFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
 at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:141)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:324)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:180)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:104)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.processElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.java:121)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.processElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.java:53)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:117)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:74)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:113)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:187)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:148)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:68)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:330)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:302)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:251)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:135)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:115)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:102)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: INTERNAL: GOAWAY received
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.ApplianceShuffleReader.readIncludingPosition(Native Method)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.ChunkingShuffleBatchReader.read(ChunkingShuffleBatchReader.java:62)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.CachingShuffleBatchReader$1.load(CachingShuffleBatchReader.java:57)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.CachingShuffleBatchReader$1.load(CachingShuffleBatchReader.java:53)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3628)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2336)
 ... 62 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a transient network error. In a distributed system transient errors are bound to happen, so Dataflow retries failures a few times (but it logs them because they sometimes knowing about them can be useful). If your job is succeeding, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have a lot of shuffling going on. This error never showed up until recently when we added another step to the job which caused more shuffling and memory usage. We had sort of the same assumption as you outlined. I just wanted to put something out here because I didn't know if this was the sort of error that suggests things will be really bad in the future as we add more and more data.

Comment: If you're shuffling a very large amount of data, you can give a try to the Shuffle Service https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/introducing-cloud-dataflow-shuffle-for-up-to-5x-performance-improvement-in-data-analytic-pipelines